# Strange javascript causes error

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox, webkit

Any idea what this line of javascript means? It causes error on Firefox 4:

```
var g=(/(\?|&)its.kit.debug.enabled=true(&|$)/).test(d.location.search)||
 (sessionStorage&&sessionStorage["its.kit.debug.enabled"]=="true");
```

I haven't seen such a strange syntax, assigning a variable with `/ (\ ? | & ) ???`

Answer (score 3):

That's a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var regex = /(\?|&)its.kit.debug.enabled=true(&|$)/;
var g = (regex).test(d.location.search) || (sessionStorage&&sessionStorage["its.kit.debug.enabled"]=="true");
```

Answer (score 0):

it's assigning a regex test of the string in d.location.search to the variable g.  g would then be true if "its.kit.debug.enabled=true" was found.